# spring representation of graphs

Tags: analysis, graph-theory, physics, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose we have a finite graph $G$ which we want to embed in ${\bf R}^d$; fix the positions of some nodes and connect all the nodes of the graphs with ideal springs of varying strength; (i.e. there is a force between every two nodes bringing them together where the magnitude is constant times the euclidean distnance between the two nodes), and consider the equilibrium position (i.e. all non-fixed nodes have net force 0).

Now suppose that we take two adjacent nodes $a$ and $b$ whose positions were not fixed, and increase the strength of the spring that connects them, and consider the new equilibrium.  How do I show that the length of the edge between $a$ and $b$ necessrarily decreases?

I know that the "Energy" (sum of (strength * square of length of edge)) is a convex function; the energy always increases when the edge weights increase, and that if $x$ and $y$ are the equilibria before and after increasing the edge length, the energy in $x$ is greater than the energy in $y$.

Comment: I don't think the energy is convex in this case. There will be multiple stable minimums of the potential. Also your question is unclear. Are you letting the system settle to equilibrium first and *then* changing the spring between two nodes or are you changing it first and then throwing the points on the plane and waiting until they settle?

Comment: We are comparing the length of the edge $a$ $b$ between the equilibria before and after changing the spring beteen the two nodes.  The energy is a sum of squares, so is convex since the sum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: @Alex: The energy of a spring with nonzero rest length is not convex, but the question is about zero rest length springs.

Comment: @Dean: I believe the key idea is that for a convex function, $f(x)-f(x_0)\ge\nabla f(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)$. Now consider the gradient at the old equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sketch of a low tech solution:

Suppose that the graph is embedded with $ \vec{x}_i $ for $ i = 1 \cdots n $ the coordinates of the $i$th vertex. Let $ k_{ij} $ be the spring constant connecting vertices $ i $ and $ j$. Suppose the first $ m $ vertices are free, and the remaining $ n-m $ are fixed. You can check that the equilibrium position $ \vec{x} $ solves the matrix equation
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-\sum_{j = 1}^{n} k_{1j}  & k_{12} & \cdots & k_{1m} \\
k_{21} & -\sum_j k_{2j} & \cdots & k_{2m}  \\
\vdots & & \ddots  \\
 k_{m1}& k_{m2} & \cdots & -\sum_j k_{mj}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{x}_1 \\
\vec{x}_2 \\
\vdots \\
\vec{x}_m
\end{pmatrix}
= -\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{j = m+1}^n  k_{1j} \vec{x}_j \\ \sum_j k_{2j} \vec{x}_j \\ \vdots \\ \sum_j k_{mj} \vec{x}_j
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Write the above equation as $ M x = v $. Suppose you are increasing $ k_{12} $. Differentiate the above equation with respect to $k_{12} $ to find:
$$ 
\frac{dM}{d  k_{12} } x + M \frac{d x}{dk_{12}} =  0 
$$
Now since $ \frac{dM}{d  k_{12} } $ looks like: $$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix} $$
You can interpret the equation:
$$ 
 M \frac{d x}{dk_{12}} =  -\frac{dM}{d  k_{12} } x
$$
as solving for the equilibrium position of the spring system with the same spring constants, with only $ \frac{d x_1}{dk_{12}} $ and $ \frac{d x_2}{dk_{12}} $ attached by springs to fixed external points at $ \pm (x_2 - x_1) $ . You can finish up to argue that it follows that $ \frac{d x}{dk_{12}} $ decreases the distance between $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $.

Comment: Shouldn't the RHS have negative signs in front of the sums in the first matrix equation?

Comment: Yes it should. Thanks.